# jscs lint error 'Expect valid jsdoc-block definition'

Tags: javascript, lint, jscs

I'm using the jscs linter. I get this error writing a standard function like this

```
function foo (param) {
    return param;
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: maybe the empty space between foo & (param) ? Any chance to see perhaps the error in detail?

Comment: Nope, I've tried all different possibilities. It's something else.

Comment: did you add a documentation block above it? Are you enforced to add documentation to your functions with the jscs linter?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. I tried to add one, it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
/** 
* Just a function
* 
* @param {Object} param
*/
function foo(param) {
    return param;
}
```